# found issue while run this command cmd := exec.Command("docker", "cp", container.ID+":"+filename, destDir+filename) in docker container

Tags: docker

while i execute my go code in window running fine while i create a image and run the same code it showing :-

exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
2018/09/05 05:49:36 Command finished with error: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

for reference code snip:[golang code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsMyd.png)

Comment: If you run this command *inside the container*, then you’re trying to copy something from *a container inside the container*. Is that what you want? And if so, do you have Docker installed inside the container?

Comment: Copy paste your code not picture please.

Comment: @Aankhen,Yes i am trying to fetch out some information from docker in respect to running container.

Comment: It not find the `docker` command, did you mount `unix domain socket` of docker? See my answer.

Comment: @atline,Yes Sir !! I am using it.Let me explain in slightly details:-when i am running go code from my local window machine its running fine and fetches the information from running container,but doing same things  after creating image and with the help of container its showing mentioned issue.

Comment: You have a `containerA`, you first run your `go code` on host pc, your code get the file from `containerA`, above is ok. Then, you run the `go code` in `containerB`, want to fetch the file again from `containerA`, then fail, if I misunderstand you?

Comment: No exactly like that actually i run the image from host machine so it get file and information regarding the all running container on host machine then i tried to copy that information in some specific location , that why i used that copy command in my go code,logic is to find the info regarding running container and saving that at particulate location.

Comment: this is my outputs-----:Info regarding contains:---
/docker-salaryApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
A:7392e696a77b7c37fed9f1f1bf2579b83b1013fd9ff1a1139afcdd0add361fa7:/docker-salaryApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
B:/backup_app/docker-salaryApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2018/09/05 10:47:01 Running command and waiting for it to finish...
exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
2018/09/05 10:47:01 Command finished with error: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

Answer (score 0):

You need to make container also know `docker command`, add `unix domain socket` of docker as a volumn & also docker binary as a volumn may help you.

```
docker run --privileged -d -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock YOUR_IMAGE
```

Of course, you need to add above `flags` to your own `docker run command` to make your application ok.

Comment: Remember that this essentially gives your container unrestricted root access over the host, which you may or may not want.